# Passing $* with parameters with spaces to a second script

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-expansion

I've got a script that takes a variable number of parameters. I also have a wrapper script where I take the same parameters and add some more. The problem is that when I have params with spaces they get split by words when passed to the "inside" script.

For example the outside script:

```bsh
# tst1.sh

echo "-- tst1.sh --"
echo "1: $1"
echo "2: $2"

./tst2.sh $* --some --more --params
```

And the inside script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo "-- tst2.sh --"
echo "1: $1"
echo "2: $2"
```

Now when I call the wrapper script it gets the *date* correct as a single parameter, however the inside one only gets the first word:

```
$ ./tst1.sh --date "$(date)"
-- tst1.sh --
1: --date
2: Fri Jan 25 21:51:57 GMT 2019

-- tst2.sh --
1: --date
2: Fri                            <== this is wrong
```

I want the output of the second script the same as the first one. And all that for a variable number of parameters, that's why I use `$*` and not individual `$1`, `$2`, etc that I could quote.

I tried quoting `"$*"` but that then joins the `--date` and the actual date string as a single parameter.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Another approach would be to use zsh instead of bash.  Handling this particular situation with less direction from the programmer is one of its better features.  However, it is still a shell, so you still need to keep quoting in mind to some extent more than in more formal scripting languages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `"$@"`:

```
./tst2.sh "$@" --some --more --params
```

The difference between `$*` and `"$@"` is that `$*` will be a *single string* consisting of the concatenation of all the positional parameters with the first character of `$IFS` as delimiter (this string would additionally undergo word-splitting and filename expansion since it's unquoted), while `"$@"` (note the double quotes!) will be each positional parameter *individually quoted*.

When wanting to preserve the individual positional parameters, always use `"$@"`.

When wanting to join the positional parameters on the first character of `$IFS` to create a *single string*, use `"$*"`.  This is rarely used apart from when creating text strings under some circumstances.

It rarely makes sense to use `$*` or `$@` unquoted.

Short example of `"$@"` vs. `"$*"`:

```
set -- "bumblebee 1" "bumblebee 2"
IFS=,

printf 'With "$@": %s\n' "$@"
printf 'With "$*": %s\n' "$*"
```

Output (with added annotations)

```
With "$@": bumblebee 1               <-- "$1" here
With "$@": bumblebee 2               <-- "$2" here
With "$*": bumblebee 1,bumblebee 2   <-- "$1$IFS$2" here
```